# create a random URL with each Instance

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on the security part of one of the upcoming websites developed based on ASP mvc. Here the target is like below.

I enter say `localhost:12345` I get redirected to `localhost:1234/Login`, But my requirement is as below.

Every time an user enters `localhost:12345`, it should create a random number and it should be shown to user as `localhost:12345/{hereIsTheRandomAlphaNumericStringGenerated}`, for example say user 1 is logged in, he is having the url as `localhost:12345/user!Rand123` and there is another user logged in and his URL should be `localhost:12345/a12fer43r5`. if someone enters this randomly generated URL to their web page, it should give an error. The base underying URL should be the same Login, but the names should be generated randomly. And also, if the user enters `localhost:12345/login` even in this case, the user should not be permitted.

in my RouteConfig.cs I've the below code available.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace ComplianceBot
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Login",
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can I do this.

Comment: But why? What problem is that going to solve? This definitely sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This way I want to avoid a direct access to the webpage, this is something that's very crucial and is going to be in a conference, we don't want someone else to start fiddling before the beta hits. I know this is very tricky and complicated, but Still I need this :)

Comment: It's just way too convoluted. Just put the entire site behind a login, and disable user registration.

Comment: Yes got it, but my website is something like this, the authentication is done using a face recognition. There is a conference that will be held and here we have to give a snapshot of the live working code. And here I don't want to risk it. A lot of hackers around in the conference. ;)